# req.flash not working with the res.redirect

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, flash-message, connect-flash

I am somewhat new to the node and express world so please forgive any of my nobe mistakes, I have a couple of methods that are returning me 500 after I use something like this.

[image: refrence to the error]

```
req.flash('success', 'your password has been successfully changed.');
res.redirect('/user-profile');
```

also I have tried sending status with it like

```
res.redirect(302,'/user-profile');
```

but it also didn't worked out

and when i try to reload the page it works fine (on the second attempt), however if I comment req.flash every things starts to work out just fine, seems like it's causing the issue while it works fine with other methods where I am using it like

```
req.flash('success', 'You are logged out');
res.redirect('/login');
```

Code in my index.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const app = require('../app');
const User = require('../model/user');
const passport = require('passport');
let path = require('path');
router.get('/user-profile', (req,res,next) => {
    res.render('profile',{
        title: 'Profile'
    });
});

router.get('/logout', (req,res,next) => {
    req.logout();
    req.flash('success', 'You are logged out');
    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

Code in my app.js

```
// Express Messages Middleware
app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
    next();
});
```

I have tried to find the solution online, but could not get it working. I am really finding it hard to debug any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're getting 500 errors, there should be errors being logged by the server.

Comment: @robertklep where could those be??? where should i be finding them??

Comment: How do you start the server?

Comment: i start it using nodemon, and there's only 500 error for get /profile route in the terminal, nothing more

Comment: Try starting it manually (`node yourserver.js`), so you get to see any debug messages.

Comment: @robertklep it's says still the same. I have updated my question with the picture of the error. could you have a look at it please.

Comment: The picture isn't very helpful. It looks like you're running your code in "production" mode, which also isn't very helpful because it obfuscates any errors that are occurring. Try adding a custom error handler (as explained [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers)) that logs the error. Also, run your script in development mode (on Unix: `NODE_ENV=development node yourserver.js`). Also, for `connect-flash` to work properly, you need to have sessions enabled. Is that the case?

Comment: @robertklep yes they're enabled too and i am currently saving them into my database.

Comment: @robertklep double checked the error handling, it's not running in the production environment.

Comment: In that case, I have no idea where the errors is coming from :(

Comment: @robertklep anyways thanks robertklep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my error long time ago, in case anyone else is facing the same problem.Here is the answer to it. I had a duplicate of <%- messages() %> in my single ejs file which was causing the issue which eventually was crashing the app.